# Bootstrap 3: Reverse Animated Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Seen answers for 2.0, but they seem to work differently for 3.0.

I want to reverse the progress bar animation in Bootstrap 3, so it moves left to right, rather than the default right to left.

I've looked in the Bootstrap CSS, and there is `transition: width .6s ease;` however I'm not sure how it determines which way the stripe effect moves.

Thanks.

Comment: The `transition` property is for when the progress bar actually moves/fills up, the animation settings are somewhere else.

Comment: If it can help, here is another (partially) working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901898/bootstrap-reverse-animated-progress-bar-like-github

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make the progress bar animate from left to right, you can do this by setting the `animation-direction` property to `reverse`.

In BS3's css file there is this section:

```
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
          animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
```

You can add a class of your own to add the required setting (default is `normal`):

```
.progress.active.my-reverse-class .progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
     -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
      -ms-animation-direction: reverse;
       -o-animation-direction: reverse;
          animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

However, note that UX studies have shown that right-to-left animation for progress bars feels "faster" to most users: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/why-do-progress-bars-animate-backwards

Comment: Thanks, works! Yep indeed it does seem a tad slower, however it's not a problem for what I'm working on.

Answer (score 5):

Ooh! Ooh! I got this one. You can swap the direction of the progress bar by setting the bar as `float: right`. It should function exactly the same.

Comment: If this works, this should totally be the accepted answer.

Comment: This works! Please accept this as answer. Pretty simple and incredibly powerful!

Answer (score 5):

I solved it rotating the progress bar, here is an example:

```
.progress-bar {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGYqrx

Comment: You can use this property again on the inner text, to reverse it back.

Comment: This was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

progress bar animate from **right to left**:

```
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
          animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
```

progress bar animate from **left to right**:

```
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
          animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
```